# How to use TFrecord file in custom CNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras, tfrecord

I want to build ANPR system on custom CNN architecture that I designed. My image dataset is in TFrecord format, how to load it as model.fit(X,y).
.pbtxt file has following stucture.

```
item {
    name: "Vehicle-registration-plate",
    id: 1,
    display_name: "Vehicle-registration-plate"
}
```

I tried official TFRecord guide.
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord
It didn't help